# How do I Install and Use Awesome WM?

Tags: awesome

How do I use Awesome WM with Ubuntu 12.04? How do I invoke Awesome instead of Unity? Any dangers to trying to install it - in other words can I mess up my graphical shell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There should be no problem installing it as `lightdm` controls what environment you log in to.  After installing it, log out and click to the right of your name and awesome will be listed there.

Note: recent version of ubuntu (13.10) comes with a bug preventing the awesome session from displaying. See [how to add awesome on session list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382307/how-to-add-awesome-on-session-list/421700#421700) for further detail.

Comment: The install will indeed create an awesome login session, so I've updated your answer to reflect this.

Comment: The OP used a `gdm` tag.  Presumably it should work the same way for `gdm` as for `lightdm`....

Comment: Actually on further research I believe I am using lightdm, if that is the default display manager for Ubuntu 11.10 & 12.04.

Comment: Yes, it's the default since 11.10.  So there's no danger...just install and login through the awesome session.