# How to install and use AwesomeWM alongside Unity?

Tags: unity, window-manager, awesome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use Awesome WM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128142/how-do-i-install-and-use-awesome-wm)

How to install and use AwesomeWM in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: **Duplicate** of http://askubuntu.com/q/128142/43660

Answer (score 1):

Simply type the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install awesome
```

LightDM automatically adds an entry for `awesome` on installation, so you will be able to start an `awesome` session from the login screen.