# how to add awesome on session list

Tags: session, awesome

Dear experts I am new to Ubuntu. I am using gnome shell and  willing to use awesome windows manager.

I am supposed to search for the tutorials before asking here and I did a lots of googling and their tutorials . What I felt is they have only  focused on how to configure awesome. I want to see awesome on my session list.

I already did a lot of things as they say but didn't work out please make an easy tutorial.

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/128142/how-do-i-install-and-use-awesome-wm

Comment: that thread didn't help sir awesome is not listed i'm using gnome shell there are three sessions gnome,gnome classic,ubuntu default

Comment: with all your expert help i could fuse awesome on my session list under gnome and open it but felt some lackness no app list and some dialogue keeps on appearing no window maneger is selected it is a sub session under ububntu i wanted it saperately please help

Comment: Not a dupe, new problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using a recent version of ubuntu (13.10), after installing awesome, it is hidden by default - [here's a bug page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/awesome/+bug/1094811/). According to comment 18, it's been fixed in trusty.

Edit /usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop and remove "NoDisplay=true"