# Setup custom window snapping in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, unity, window-manager, window

I recently purchased an ultrawide monitor, and I'm using it with Ubuntu.

Unity comes by default with a way to snap things into the corners or half the screen, but I'd like a to be able to split my screen into 1/3s side by side.  Also, in general I'd like to be able to customize the snapping easily, so I could change to say, four apps side by side if desired.

I've looked but It doesn't seem like a common issue and thus, there are few tutorials on it.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/questions/94859/resizing-windows-to-a-particular-width-and-height-instantly  You could set up a key or a gesture to resize a particular window.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/576694/72216 maybe not literally what you asked for, but should be close enough.

Comment: You can almost do that without installing anything by using Ctrl + Alt + the keys in the num pad. When you are on any application window if you press those keys the window will resize and move to the corners, top, bottom or full screen.

Comment: @RamonSuarez, I know, but I'm looking for more options beyond those that come from compiz by default.

Answer (score 5):

For managing multiple apps/ windows, it's always good to use a tiling window manager instead of the regular desktop.

[Tiling window manager Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager)

Consider trying,
[Awesome Window Manager](https://awesomewm.org/download/)

Very much customizable, guaranteed improvements in productivity.

[image]

Here is the [Overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2Dx3jGunCI) youtube link.

Comment: Interesting, do you know if you can use a tiling window manager while still using unity?  Like can I still have the launch bar and all the other features of unity, while just changing the way the windows are laid out?

Comment: You can't use  _awesome_ inside  _unity_  but you can install  _awesome_ along with _unity_ , just select _awesome_ while login. [Awesome instalation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/128142/how-do-i-install-and-use-awesome-wm?rq=1) [Documentation](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/?redirected_from_wiki=1)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need i3, which is a tiling window manager. It has a steep learning curve though.
https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html